# Change EdgeDB default dbschema directory

Tags: edgedb

The documentation says:

> By convention, your schema files should live in a directory called dbschema in the root of your project.

How can I set it into another directory? I want to place it in inner directory in my project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your project's `edgedb.toml` file:

```
schema-directory = <schema-dir>
```